# Archiving files once with rsync

Tags: backup, archive, rsync

Is there a way for rsync to archive files only once to the destination? So that if I delete a file on the target after they were archived, the rsync won't re-copy it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that by using only rsync, this is not possible, since it would be required to use some kind of database / additional coding, to keep track of files that that were once synced.

Maybe rsync is the wrong approach for this use case?

The other way around, to skip existing files on the target from being synced, you can use `--ignore-existing`, also consider to take a look at the man page.